# Circular Walk in a string

Tags: string, dynamic-programming

You are given a string in which 'A' means you can move 1 step clockwise, 'C' means you can move one step anticlockwise and '?' means you can move one step either clockwise or anti clockwise. So Given a string find maximum distance from inital position at any given point of time.

for eg:- 
input : - AACC?CC
output :- 3
explanation : - if ? is replaced with C then max distance will become 3

optimal approach to solve this problem?

Comment: This site is not about solving programming / algorithm questions. Please add some code that shows what you have already tried.

Comment: I didn't ask to solve. Just asked for the approach.

Comment: Ok, for an approach you can think about counting the 'A' characters and the 'C' characters, take the maximum and add the number of '?'.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "AACC?CC"
count = 0
extra = 0
for i in str:
    if i == 'A':
        count -= 1
    elif i == 'C':
        count += 1
    else:
        extra += 1

dist = abs(count) + extra
if count < 0:
    print "AntiClockwise:",
else:
    print "ClockWise:",
print dist
```

Just try this out. however 'A', 'C' movements must be taken place, so you should go left and right. the '?'is optional. You can just count How many '?' are there and add it to the final answer.